# How to use awk to extract the required columns and create a new file?

Tags: linux, awk, cut, bioinformatics

I have `gtf` files in more than 100 directories. Below I'm showing how they look.

```
SampleA
   |___________ SampleA.GRCh38.gtf
SampleB
   |___________ SampleB.GRCh38.gtf
```

Here I'm showing only two `gtf` files as an example.

`SampleA.GRCh38.gtf` looks like below:

```
# stringtie -e -B -p 8 -G /path/stringtie_output/stringtie_merged.gtf -o /path/SampleA.GRCh38.gtf /path/SampleA.sorted.bam
# StringTie version 1.3.3
chr1    StringTie       transcript      11594   191502  .       -       .       gene_id "MSTRG.7542"; transcript_id "MSTRG.7542.2"; cov "0.0"; FPKM "0.000000"; TPM "0.000000";
chr1    StringTie       exon    11594   14829   .       -       .       gene_id "MSTRG.7542"; transcript_id "MSTRG.7542.2"; exon_number "1"; cov "0.0";
chr1    StringTie       exon    14970   15038   .       -       .       gene_id "MSTRG.7542"; transcript_id "MSTRG.7542.2"; exon_number "2"; cov "0.0";
chr1    StringTie       exon    15796   16765   .       -       .       gene_id "MSTRG.7542"; transcript_id "MSTRG.7542.2"; exon_number "3"; cov "0.0";
chr1    StringTie       exon    16858   17055   .       -       .       gene_id "MSTRG.7542"; transcript_id "MSTRG.7542.2"; exon_number "4"; cov "0.0";
chr1    StringTie       exon    17233   17742   .       -       .       gene_id "MSTRG.7542"; transcript_id "MSTRG.7542.2"; exon_number "5"; cov "0.0";
chr1    StringTie       exon    17915   18061   .       -       .       gene_id "MSTRG.7542"; transcript_id "MSTRG.7542.2"; exon_number "6"; cov "0.0";
chr1    StringTie       exon    18268   19364   .       -       .       gene_id "MSTRG.7542"; transcript_id "MSTRG.7542.2"; exon_number "7"; cov "0.0";
chr1    StringTie       exon    189836  191502  .       -       .       gene_id "MSTRG.7542"; transcript_id "MSTRG.7542.2"; exon_number "8"; cov "0.0";
chr1    StringTie       transcript      11594   195411  .       -       .       gene_id "MSTRG.7542"; transcript_id "MSTRG.7542.6"; cov "0.0"; FPKM "0.000000"; TPM "0.000000";
chr1    StringTie       exon    11594   14829   .       -       .       gene_id "MSTRG.7542"; transcript_id "MSTRG.7542.6"; exon_number "1"; cov "0.0";
chr1    StringTie       exon    14970   15236   .       -       .       gene_id "MSTRG.7542"; transcript_id "MSTRG.7542.6"; exon_number "2"; cov "0.0";
chr1    StringTie       exon    185758  187287  .       -       .       gene_id "MSTRG.7542"; transcript_id "MSTRG.7542.6"; exon_number "3"; cov "0.0";
chr1    StringTie       exon    187376  187577  .       -       .       gene_id "MSTRG.7542"; transcript_id "MSTRG.7542.6"; exon_number "4"; cov "0.0";
chr1    StringTie       exon    187755  187890  .       -       .       gene_id "MSTRG.7542"; transcript_id "MSTRG.7542.6"; exon_number "5"; cov "0.0";
chr1    StringTie       exon    188130  188266  .       -       .       gene_id "MSTRG.7542"; transcript_id "MSTRG.7542.6"; exon_number "6"; cov "0.0";
chr1    StringTie       exon    188439  188584  .       -       .       gene_id "MSTRG.7542"; transcript_id "MSTRG.7542.6"; exon_number "7"; cov "0.0";
chr1    StringTie       exon    188791  188902  .       -       .       gene_id "MSTRG.7542"; transcript_id "MSTRG.7542.6"; exon_number "8"; cov "0.0";
chr1    StringTie       exon    195263  195411  .       -       .       gene_id "MSTRG.7542"; transcript_id "MSTRG.7542.6"; exon_number "9"; cov "0.0";
chr1    StringTie       transcript      11594   197912  .       -       .       gene_id "MSTRG.7542"; transcript_id "MSTRG.7542.5"; cov "0.0"; FPKM "0.000000"; TPM "0.000000";
```

And `SampleB.GRCh38.gtf` looks like below:

```
# stringtie -e -B -p 8 -G /path/stringtie_output/stringtie_merged.gtf -o /path/SampleB.GRCh38.gtf /path/SampleB.sorted.bam
# StringTie version 1.3.3
chr1    StringTie       transcript      11594   191502  .       -       .       gene_id "MSTRG.7542"; transcript_id "MSTRG.7542.2"; cov "0.0"; FPKM "0.000000"; TPM "1.000000";
chr1    StringTie       exon    11594   14829   .       -       .       gene_id "MSTRG.7542"; transcript_id "MSTRG.7542.2"; exon_number "1"; cov "0.0";
chr1    StringTie       exon    14970   15038   .       -       .       gene_id "MSTRG.7542"; transcript_id "MSTRG.7542.2"; exon_number "2"; cov "0.0";
chr1    StringTie       exon    15796   16765   .       -       .       gene_id "MSTRG.7542"; transcript_id "MSTRG.7542.2"; exon_number "3"; cov "0.0";
chr1    StringTie       exon    16858   17055   .       -       .       gene_id "MSTRG.7542"; transcript_id "MSTRG.7542.2"; exon_number "4"; cov "0.0";
chr1    StringTie       exon    17233   17742   .       -       .       gene_id "MSTRG.7542"; transcript_id "MSTRG.7542.2"; exon_number "5"; cov "0.0";
chr1    StringTie       exon    17915   18061   .       -       .       gene_id "MSTRG.7542"; transcript_id "MSTRG.7542.2"; exon_number "6"; cov "0.0";
chr1    StringTie       exon    18268   19364   .       -       .       gene_id "MSTRG.7542"; transcript_id "MSTRG.7542.2"; exon_number "7"; cov "0.0";
chr1    StringTie       exon    189836  191502  .       -       .       gene_id "MSTRG.7542"; transcript_id "MSTRG.7542.2"; exon_number "8"; cov "0.0";
chr1    StringTie       transcript      11594   195411  .       -       .       gene_id "MSTRG.7542"; transcript_id "MSTRG.7542.6"; cov "0.0"; FPKM "0.000000"; TPM "3.000000";
chr1    StringTie       exon    11594   14829   .       -       .       gene_id "MSTRG.7542"; transcript_id "MSTRG.7542.6"; exon_number "1"; cov "0.0";
chr1    StringTie       exon    14970   15236   .       -       .       gene_id "MSTRG.7542"; transcript_id "MSTRG.7542.6"; exon_number "2"; cov "0.0";
chr1    StringTie       exon    185758  187287  .       -       .       gene_id "MSTRG.7542"; transcript_id "MSTRG.7542.6"; exon_number "3"; cov "0.0";
chr1    StringTie       exon    187376  187577  .       -       .       gene_id "MSTRG.7542"; transcript_id "MSTRG.7542.6"; exon_number "4"; cov "0.0";
chr1    StringTie       exon    187755  187890  .       -       .       gene_id "MSTRG.7542"; transcript_id "MSTRG.7542.6"; exon_number "5"; cov "0.0";
chr1    StringTie       exon    188130  188266  .       -       .       gene_id "MSTRG.7542"; transcript_id "MSTRG.7542.6"; exon_number "6"; cov "0.0";
chr1    StringTie       exon    188439  188584  .       -       .       gene_id "MSTRG.7542"; transcript_id "MSTRG.7542.6"; exon_number "7"; cov "0.0";
chr1    StringTie       exon    188791  188902  .       -       .       gene_id "MSTRG.7542"; transcript_id "MSTRG.7542.6"; exon_number "8"; cov "0.0";
chr1    StringTie       exon    195263  195411  .       -       .       gene_id "MSTRG.7542"; transcript_id "MSTRG.7542.6"; exon_number "9"; cov "0.0";
chr1    StringTie       transcript      11594   197912  .       -       .       gene_id "MSTRG.7542"; transcript_id "MSTRG.7542.5"; cov "0.0"; FPKM "0.000000"; TPM "0.000000";
```

I want to extract only `transcript` from 3rd column and `transcript_id` which is 10th column and `TPM` which is the last column. But `TPM` needs to be the Sample names.

I want the output to be looked like below:

```
Type        transcript_id      SampleA      SampleB
transcript   MSTRG.7542.2      0.000000     1.000000
transcript   MSTRG.7542.6      0.000000     3.000000
transcript   MSTRG.7542.5      0.000000     1.000000
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How To extract the whole string using awk?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/572362/how-to-extract-the-whole-string-using-awk)

Comment: @AdminBee I tried that, but didn't work. As you see in my above data there is no column names

Answer (score 0):

You will need to extract the relevant records from each file and write the result to two new temporary files (possibly using `awk`), possibly sorting it (with `sort`) at the same time (the sample files say they are sorted, but maybe not on the correct key).  Here's an example of processing one of the files:

```
awk '$3 == "transcript" {printf("%s %s %s ", $3, $10, $12, $18);}' SampleA.GRCh38.gtf | sort -k 2 > tf1
```

Then you can use `join` to merge the two temporary/intermediate files generated by `awk` so that each record has the two final columns from each file.

Here's an example of a `join` command you might use:

```
join -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,2.3 -1 2 -2 2 tf1 tf2
```

You may want to print a header line (e.g. using the `printf` command) before running `join`, and you may want to replace spaces in the `join` output with tabs (e.g. using `sed`), or use another `awk` script to format the output.

From these examples you should be able to put together a script that will process both files and produce your desired output (and clean up the temporary files, etc.).

Note that depending on the size of the data files you may even be able to do everything in one `awk` (or `python` or `perl`, etc.) program (i.e. can all the selected data from both files be held easily in memory at once).

Answer (score 0):

You can just `join` the files and then `awk` out those with `NF==4` as only those lines you are interested in have an 18th field. All the other lines will only have 2 fields

Also Making certain assumptions about calculating the path to `SampleB`, however you can amend that to suit....

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' f; do                             #read the list of SampleA
        g=$(echo "$f" | sed "s/pleA/pleB/g")               #calculate path to SampleB
        if [[ -f "$g" ]]; then                             #check SampleB exists
                echo "$f" | sed "s/.*pleA\.//g"            #print sample No
                echo "Type transcript_id SampleA SampleB"  #print header
                                                           #do the join
                join -j 12 -o 1.3 -o 1.12 -o 1.18 -o2.18 <(sort -k 12 "$f") <(sort -k 12 "$g") | awk 'NF==4'
        fi   | sed 's/[;"]//g'| column -t                  #make it pretty
done < <(find . -type f -iname "*SampleA*" -print0)        #NULL separated list of SampleA
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried with Below command

Step1

```
awk '$3 ~ /transcript/{print $0}' file1|awk '{print $3,substr($12,2,12),substr($NF,2,8)}' > out1
```

STEP2

```
awk '$3 == "transcript" {print substr($NF,2,8)}' file2  > out2
```

STEP3

```
paste out out1.txt | awk 'BEGIN{print "Type        transcript_id      SampleA      SampleB"}{print $0}'



Output

Type       transcript_id SampleA    SampleB
transcript MSTRG.7542.2 0.000000    1.000000
transcript MSTRG.7542.6 0.000000    3.000000
transcript MSTRG.7542.5 0.000000    0.000000
```